# How to convert a svg to image, where svg has a image with in svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, svg

I'm trying to convert a `svg` to image, where the `svg` has a image with-in it.

I have tried in two ways,

Method 1: using XMLSerializer

and Method 2: using [canvg](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg).

When I'm trying to convert the svg to image, the image with-in svg is skipped and rest of the svg is converted into image. I want the whole svg including image to convert into an image.

It will be helpful if you post any working code or links.

Thanks in advance.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9fymvbe1/17/)**

Comment: And what the problems and your question?

Comment: When I'm trying to convert the svg to image, the image with-in svg is skipped and rest of the svg is converted into image. I want the whole svg including image to convert into an image.

Comment: Do the conversion recursively i.e. convert the internal image, replace that and then convert the parent.